# Unable to view the Custom MMS in Available Service Applications Drop Down

Tags: managed-metadata, term-set

I have created a new MMS in production SP 2013 farm's Central Admin.When I click on the `Manage` on the ribbon for this new MMS proxy, I am unable to view the newly created MMS name.What am I missing ?

Comment: Is the service placed in the default proxy group?

Comment: my new MMS Service Application was not added in default proxy group.But it was added in custom Application proxy group.

Comment: Do I need to do any extra settings or any PowerShell scripts for enabling the newly MMS name visible in Available Service Applications dropdown?

Comment: Add it to the default proxy group from central admin, and see if becomes accessible.